# Can I use an aggregator inside another aggregator in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am a fresh learner of SQL, and now we are studying subqueries or inner queries.
My question, is subqueries are there due to impossible executing an aggregator inside another one? Such as trying to sum an do average on the same column in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

The answer is "no" (unless your database extends the standard, which Oracle does).  If you think about it, it doesn't make sense.  `avg()` returns one row per group in the result set.  The `sum()` would only operate on one row -- so it would return the same value.

If you want the sum of the averages, you can calculate them using:

```
select sum(average)
from (select x, avg(y) as average
      from t
      group by x
     ) t
```

This returns one row.  If you wanted the sum on every row, say along with the average, you would use window functions:

```
select x, avg(y) as average, sum(avg(y)) over () as sum_average
from t
group by x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregators inside aggregators if they both apply to different queries.

For example, this is illegal (since aggregators are on the same query):

```
select avg(sum(amount)) from t;
```

But this is legal (since aggregators are on different queries):

```
select avg(a) from (
  select sum(amount) as a from t group by dpmt
) x
```

In this case, one aggregation is on the main query, while the other one is in a subquery.